# Exporting a mySQL database out of Microsoft Webmatrix

Tags: database, wordpress, webmatrix

I am trying to deploy a WordPress site that was created on localhost with Microsoft Webmatrix, to a server that runs PHPmyadmin. I can copy the files over, however I'm having trouble with the mySQL database. As far as I can tell I need to export the database from Webmatrix and then import it with PHPmyadmin on the server.

I can see the mySQL database when I'm editing the site in Webmatrix, but I can't see how to export it. The instructions that I've read say to click migrate, however that button is greyed out for me. I tried to create a new database and ended up with a .sdf file (that I can migrate) however it is empty and I can't copy my actual database over to it as far as I can see. I'm running out of things to try. Any help appreciated.

Comment: from what I understand, webmarix uses ms sql server express, not mysql. but I could be wrong.

Comment: if you do use mysql however, you could get your data with the mysqldump command.